# how to write a rant?

Tags: non-fiction

Rants and ranters are numerous and pretty damn popular, so I'd just like to ask about a formula or general tips for writing them, without making my readers rage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want a character that rants using dialogue (or perhaps monologue). So, writing a rant would follow the rules of any dialogue or monologue.

No character should speak without a reason. The same goes for someone ranting. Why are they ranting? What in their background, psychology or personality makes them rant? Is it a common thing or have the drop just made the cup run over?

Also, why is there a rant in your story right here? What is its purpose? Is it building character? Showing plot? Perhaps it's a rant that also is world building? (Imagine in Sci-fi, someone ranting about the glitchy teleporter... how much tech "porn" can't be included in that kind of dialogue?)

The rant should have a function, if possible more than one. A rant for the sake of ranting is most likely going to cause the reader to start skim.

Since a rant could go on for some time, you may need to beware of too much dialogue or the whole thing could get tiresome. Try telling part of the rant instead of showing it all.

Perhaps the POV person isn't the one ranting and his/her mind starts wandering when the ranter circles back to things they have already covered, or perhaps the POV person is the one ranting and he/she feels his audience isn't listening and while ranting (not shown in the text) starts worrying about not getting the message across.

The ranting character should also face opposition. Someone trying to interrupt them, or perhaps people starting to leave. Unless your ranting person is a tech billionaire or a priest people might not want to just sit and listen.

Answer (score 5):

Rants sound childish and whiny.  If you want a rant to be something of persuasion, it needs to have the elements of a good persuasive speech.  You can study Hitler's speeches as he is considered one of the best [public speakers](http://www.businessinsider.com/why-hitler-was-such-a-successful-orator-2015-5) of the modern era.

Most of his speeches were rants.  They were complaining about the ruined state of Germany, and those who were to blame for it.  The difference though, is he didn't sound like a child complaining and throwing a tantrum.  He sounded like someone with passion and care for the people like they haven't seen before/in a while.  He spoke with conviction and charm using all the right words to get the change and the results he wanted.

To do this successfully, the topic will be something you also feel charged about or else it will lose it's edge and it will feel flat.  The whole point of a rant is to move people and at the very least, have them feel empathy for your point of view.  A good rant is nothing more than a well written persuasive argument spoken/written with frustration and passion.

Nobody wants to hear someone complain and throw a tantrum, but people might listen if your argument is solid and passionate and speaking to the issues that need to be changed.

Comment: Sorry, there's no way to be objective about the rhetorical skills of this particular speaker. I must on principle DV anything which uses him as an example of something to emulate. He was evil. His ideas were evil. His goals were evil. The only reason to study his evil speeches is to use them as warning signs.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum  then you clearly can't appreciate good public speaking even if it's from an evil source.  He is used widely in public speaking classes as an example for persuasive speaking.  Sorry you let bias control you.

Comment: I *have* taken public speaking classes and he was not used as an example. And yes, my bias against him would be such that I could not learn, so there would be no point in the teacher using those speeches.